# Django REST Framework login and logout views

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm building a system using django, django rest framework, django oauth toolkit, django axes in a microservices architecture but I have some doubts. Currently I have my "login" view on the client that takes the username and password from the POST request and sends it to my "UserLoginAPI" API, in the "UserLoginApi" view I validate the user and password in the "UserLoginSerializer" serializer, I check if the user is not blocked in django axes and I create a token for this user with oauth, the serializer returns the authenticated user and the token and "UserLoginApi" updates the last_login with update_last_login, I saw in a discussion on stackoverflow that it should be used update_last_login instead of login(request, user), then I return the token back to the "login" view on the client, and on the client I take this token and store it in the session and with middleware I check in each request if the token exists and if the token exists, if it has already expired, if it exists and has not expired, I update the session user with the user associated with the token. And at logout I do the same thing but I use logout(request) to log out the user and send a signal to axes to know that the user has been logged out. What I want to know is if my logic done so far is correct, if I created a correct authentication system. I also wanted to know how I can validate only certain views with my middleware, I only wanted to authenticate views that have the @login_required decorator to prevent the middleware from working on pages that the user can access without being logged in, such as the login page. login, reset password and others

```
def login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    api_url = f'{BASE_URL}/UserLoginAPI/'  
    data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
    }

    try:

        response = api_request.make_post_request(api_url, data=data)

        if response['status'] == status.HTTP_200_OK:
            access_token = response.get('access_token')
            request.session['access_token'] = access_token
            return redirect('home')
        elif response['status'] in [status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]:
            messages.error(request, response['message'], extra_tags='error')   

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        messages.error(request, 'Erro ao fazer login', extra_tags='error')

return render(request, r'login\login.html')

def logout(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.user

    api_url = f'{BASE_URL}/UserLogoutAPI/'  
    data = {
        'username': username,
    }

    try:

        response = api_request.make_post_request(api_url, data=data)

        if response['status'] == status.HTTP_200_OK:
            return redirect('login')
        elif response['status'] in [status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]:
            messages.error(request, response['message'], extra_tags='error')

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        messages.error(request, 'Erro ao deslogar', extra_tags='error')

@authentication_classes([OAuth2Authentication])
@permission_classes([TokenHasReadWriteScope])
class UserLoginAPI(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

    try:

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        access_token = serializer.validated_data['access_token']

        update_last_login(None, user)
        return Response({'success': 'Login bem sucedido', 'access_token': access_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    except ValidationError as e:
        error_message = str(e.detail['non_field_errors'][0])
        log_error(request.path, error_message, None)
        return Response({'error': error_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except Exception as e:
        log_error(request.path, str(e), None)
        return Response({'error': 'Erro ao fazer login'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    
@authentication_classes([OAuth2Authentication])
@permission_classes([TokenHasReadWriteScope])     
class UserLogoutAPI(APIView):
def post(self, request):

    serializer = UserLogoutSerializer(data=request.data)

    try:

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']

        logout(request)
        signals.user_logged_out.send(sender=User, request=request, user=user)
        return Response({'success': 'Usuário deslogado com sucesso'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    except ValidationError as e:
        error_message = str(e.detail['non_field_errors'][0])
        log_error(request.path, error_message, user)
        return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except Exception as e:
        log_error(request.path, str(e), user)
        return Response({'error': 'Erro ao deslogar'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
username = serializers.CharField()
password = serializers.CharField()

def validate(self, data):
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')
    request = self.context.get('request')
  
    if AxesProxyHandler().is_locked(request):
        raise ValidationError('O usuário está bloqueado por múltiplas tentativas falhas de login, aguarde 30 minutos antes de tentar entrar novamente')

    user = authenticate(request=request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is None or not user.is_active:
        raise ValidationError('Usuário ou senha inválidos')

    existing_token = AccessToken.objects.filter(
            user=user,
            expires__gt=timezone.now()
    ).first()

    if existing_token:
        access_token = existing_token
    else:
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(
            user=user,
            token=generate_token(),
            application=Application.objects.get(name='application_login'),
            expires=timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=60),
        )
    
    return {'user': user, 'access_token': access_token.token}  

class UserLogoutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
username = serializers.CharField()

def validate(self, data):
    username = data.get('username')

    user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    if not user or not user.is_active:
        raise ValidationError('Usuário inválido')
    
    existing_token = AccessToken.objects.filter(
            user = user,
            expires__gt = timezone.now()
        ).first()

    existing_token.expires = timezone.now()  
    existing_token.save()
    
    return {'user': user}

class TokenAuthenticationMiddleware:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    session_token = request.session.get('access_token')

    if session_token:
        try:
            access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=session_token)

            if access_token.expires < timezone.now():
                request.user = AnonymousUser()
                messages.error(request, "Sua sessão expirou, faça o login novamente")
            else:
                request.user = access_token.user
                log_path(request.path, request.user)
        except AccessToken.DoesNotExist:
            request.user = AnonymousUser()
            messages.error(request, "Acesso negado, faça login para continuar")
    else:
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
        messages.error(request, "Acesso negado, faça login para continuar")
 
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

If you can point out if I'm on the right path or if I need to improve something, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do with `api_request.make_post_request(api_url, data=data)`. Isn't that endpoint you are making a request to the same server itself? Why make a request from the server to the server itself? Just run whatever code you need to run?

Comment: The "login" and "logout" view that makes the "api_request" is on the client side and the "UserLoginAPI" and "UserLogoutAPI" are on the server backend, it is a specific microservice for logging in and logging out

Comment: It's all together here because I couldn't properly separate the code on stackoverflow

Comment: Please have a look at the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then, your post surely needs it. Try to break down your single paragraph into multiple ones as well.